# Using MS's column formatting JSON to change the color of a cell based on the first 2 characters

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I'm trying to use the JSON conditional formatting based on the first 2 characters of a field value, and have not had much luck with it. Any help will be greatly appreciated, here is a variation of what I have been trying to run but with no luck.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "<",
          "operands": [
            "[$LinkTitle].substring(0, 2);",
            "95"
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-LightGrayFont",
        ""
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Title]"
}
```

Comment: I have also tried {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(([$Title].substring(0,2)) < 70,'sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(([$Title].substring(0,2)) < 70,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "[$Title]"}
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are using `substring` and that you are mixing [AST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#abstract-syntax-tree-expressions) (operator/operand junk) with [excel style expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#excel-style-expressions) (inline). You should be able to use this to accomplish what you want:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": { 
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number(substring([$LinkTitle],0,2)) < 95, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-LightGrayFont', '')"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Title]"
}
```

---

Similarly, you can make the same adjustments for the format you pasted in the comment:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number(substring([$Title],0,2)) < 70,'sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(Number(substring([$Title],0,2)) < 70,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "[$Title]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This JSON seems to always fail not matter what and the text for the field/column disappears or its not being repopulated.  Here is what I'm running on the Class section :``` "class": "=if(Number(substring([$Mon],0,2)) < 95,'sp-field-severity--severeWarning',if(Number(substring([$Mon],0,2)) >= 95,'sp-field-severity--good', '')" ``` and```  "iconName": "=if(Number(substring([$Mon],0,2)) < 95,'Error',if(Number(substring([$Mon],0,2)) >= 95,'CompletedSolid', ''))"  }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "[$Mon]"
    }
  ]
}``` Any ideas on what might be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Had to change from field-specific "[$Mon]" to `@currentField` and it works just fine. @theChrisKent, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number(substring(@currentField,2,0)) < 95,'sp-field-severity--severeWarning',if(Number(substring(@currentField,2,0)) >= 95,'sp-field-severity--good', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(Number(substring(@currentField,2,0)) < 95,'Error',if(Number(substring(@currentField,2,0)) >= 95,'CompletedSolid', ''))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```